# Is 0.7 - 0.75 an acceptable accuracy for Naive Bayes sentiment analysis?

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes

I apologise in advance for posting so much code.

I am trying to classify YouTube comments into ones that contain opinion (be it positive or negative) and ones that don't using NLTK's Naive Bayes classifier, but no matter what I do during the preprocessing stage I can't really get the accuracy above 0.75. This seems kinda low compared to other examples I have seen - [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-perform-sentiment-analysis-in-python-3-using-the-natural-language-toolkit-nltk) tutorial ends up with an accuracy of around 0.98 for example.

Here is my full code

```
import nltk, re, json, random

from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
from nltk import FreqDist, classify, NaiveBayesClassifier

from contractions import CONTRACTION_MAP
from abbreviations import abbrev_map
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

def expand_contractions(text, contraction_mapping=CONTRACTION_MAP):
    text = re.sub(r"’", "'", text)
    if text in abbrev_map:
        return(abbrev_map[text])
    text = re.sub(r"\bluv", "lov", text)
    
    contractions_pattern = re.compile('({})'.format('|'.join(contraction_mapping.keys())), 
                                      flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
    def expand_match(contraction):
        match = contraction.group(0)
        first_char = match[0]
        expanded_contraction = contraction_mapping.get(match)\
                                if contraction_mapping.get(match)\
                                else contraction_mapping.get(match.lower())                       
        expanded_contraction = first_char+expanded_contraction[1:]
        return expanded_contraction
        
    expanded_text = contractions_pattern.sub(expand_match, text)
    return expanded_text

def reduce_lengthening(text):
    pattern = re.compile(r"(.)\1{2,}")
    return pattern.sub(r"\1\1", text)

def lemmatize_sentence(tokens):
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    lemmatized_sentence = []
    for word, tag in pos_tag(tokens):
        if tag.startswith('NN'):
            pos = 'n'
        elif tag.startswith('VB'):
            pos = 'v'
        else:
            pos = 'a'
        lemmatized_sentence.append(lemmatizer.lemmatize(word, pos))
    return lemmatized_sentence

def processor(comments_list):
    
    new_comments_list = []
    for com in tqdm(comments_list):
        com = com.lower()
        
        #expand out contractions
        tok = com.split(" ")
        z = []
        for w in tok:
            ex_w = expand_contractions(w)
            z.append(ex_w)
        st = " ".join(z)
        
        
        tokenized = tokenizer.tokenize(st)
        reduced = [reduce_lengthening(token) for token in tokenized]
        new_comments_list.append(reduced)
        
    lemmatized = [lemmatize_sentence(new_com) for new_com in new_comments_list]
    
    return(lemmatized)

def get_all_words(cleaned_tokens_list):
    for tokens in cleaned_tokens_list:
        for token in tokens:
            yield token

def get_comments_for_model(cleaned_tokens_list):
    for comment_tokens in cleaned_tokens_list:
        yield dict([token, True] for token in comment_tokens)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #=================================================================================~
    tokenizer = TweetTokenizer(strip_handles=True, reduce_len=True)        
    
    with open ("english_lang/samples/training_set.json", "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
        train_data = json.load(f)
        
    pos_processed = processor(train_data['pos'])
    neg_processed = processor(train_data['neg'])
    neu_processed = processor(train_data['neu'])
    
    emotion = pos_processed + neg_processed
    random.shuffle(emotion)
    
    em_tokens_for_model = get_comments_for_model(emotion)
    neu_tokens_for_model = get_comments_for_model(neu_processed)

    em_dataset = [(comment_dict, "Emotion")
                         for comment_dict in em_tokens_for_model]

    neu_dataset = [(comment_dict, "Neutral")
                             for comment_dict in neu_tokens_for_model]

    dataset = em_dataset + neu_dataset


    random.shuffle(dataset)
    x = 700
    tr_data = dataset[:x]
    te_data = dataset[x:]
    classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(tr_data)
    print(classify.accuracy(classifier, te_data))
```

I can post my training data set if needed, but it's probably worth mentioning that the quality of English is very poor and inconsistent in the YouTube comments themselves (which I imagine is the reason for the low model accuracy). In any case, would this be considered an acceptable level of accuracy?
Alternatively, I may well be going about this all wrong and there is a far superior model to be using, in which case feel free to tell me I am an idiot!
Thanks in advance

Comment: This question might find better answers on the [data science stack exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/), so keep that in mind if you don't get answers here.

Answer (score 2):

It is not statistically valid to compare your results against those of an unrelated tutorial. Before you panic, please do appropriate research on the factors that can reduce a model's accuracy. First and foremost, your model cannot exhibit an accuracy higher than that inherent in the data set's information. For instance, no model can perform (in the long run) better than 50% in predicting a random binary event, regardless of the data set.

We have no reasonable way to evaluate the theoretical information content.  If you need a check, try applying some other model types to the same data, and see what they produce for accuracy.  Running these experiments is a normal part of data science.